# MySQL Insert User and Password at the same time, but in different tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, insert

So I have a MySQL database schema where there is a USERS table which contains the ID as a primary key for that table, I also have a USER_PASSWORDS table which references the USERS table where the USER_ID will act as a foreign key in this table.

The issue that I am facing is that I am writing an application where the user will be able to sign up and specify a username and password. But I would like to insert the user into the database with one query.

I was thinking I had to insert the username first into the USERS table and see what ID has been given to that username and then insert the hash of the password that the user has entered into the USER_PASSWORDS table and specifying the ID that was queried.

I dont like this approach because it means that I have to:

INSERT into the database
QUERY the database
INSERT into the database again

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert into two tables with one insert statement, and you would have to query the users table anyway to get the ID value to insert as a foreign key for the user_passwords table.

Really the only way to do what you want is the solution you've already identified:

1. Insert into the Users table
2. Query to get the ID of the User you just inserted
3. Insert into the USER_PASSWORDS table with the ID you obtained for the User.

You could wrap all this up in a stored procedure that takes user data and password as parameters, which would be the "better" way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: since the hash is unique you can use the hash as a primary key in the `USERS` table. Then you know what the primary key (id) is at the time of the insert and can reuse when INSERTING in the USER_PASSWORDS table.

That way you can avoid the id query at least.

Answer (score 0):

As you didnt really tell for what system / programming language you need this and you did not provide any code example either, I can only give you some theory what you could do:

Its impossible to insert data into two different MySQL tables with one queries but you can reduce your script atleast by the SELECT query:

1.) There is a function in most mysql apis (Depending on what programming language and MySQL Library you are using) that says "getLastInsertId()", "lastInsertId()" or similar.

This will return the ID that was inserted by the auto-increment of the table after the insert is completed.

Just check the docs of your MySQL-api it will have such a function.

2.)
The second possibility is using a UUID - a very large (commonly 128-bit) long string which is generated totally random. There are more so many possible combinations it will happen more probably that you win in the lottery 10 times in a row then you generate two times the same UUID that is already in your table.

So you just generate the UUID and insert it as a key in both tables and you are done.

Just use google to find out-of-the-box libraries to generate UUID's you dont need to build the alogrithm on your own.

An UUID could looks like this:
4a34fe87-f577-4ea9-9557-1bc8f779a68c

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the information. I will be writing this application in Java and I have experience in using JDBC to connect and query the database. I was wondering if Hibernate would be able to help?

Comment: You're welcome. Last insert-ID for Java JDBC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29 ---> However I am interested why in the world do you split the password hashes from the user table? Ususally each user got one password so you have a 1:1 relation which doesnt require an additional table -> confused o.O

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention  that the user will have to change their password every 3 months or so and we would like to keep a history of all the password hashes and the date they expire etc

Comment: Ah so you forbid already used passwords, a really paranoid one I see! :)